# Which JRE is required to run servlets..Server JRE or Client JRE?

Tags: java

I Am trying to run servlets so i want to know which one to download Client JRE or Server JRE as there are two JRE available on Oracle website? I have JDK 7 installed.

Comment: do you have a jdk installed?

Comment: yes i have it installed.

Comment: have you noticed a JRE folder alongwith your JDK? this one is enough for your servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the server and client VM is the different number of optimizations each one is doing (there are other differences ofcource). In other words you can run *servlets* with both VM but you will need a **servlet container** like **tomcat** or an application server. For development you will need a **JDK** which contains a JRE

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK from the Oracle's Website (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: so the JRE isnt required??

Comment: @Vanjul jre comes along with jdk. you don't need to download it separately

Comment: Ok thanks. But the thing is that my computer has two jre7 folders one in Program Files and other in Program Files(x86) . But the only difference is one jre7 folder in program files has "Server" folder and the one in Program Files(x86) has a "Client" folder. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Vanjul my computer has three JREs and each of the has JRE/bin/client folder. You have 64-bit Windows. so you have a `Program Files` folder. Windows7 ^4-bit also suports 32-bit operations. The softwares that are made for 32-bit OS are installed in `Programs Files(x86)`. The difference between client and server jre is already  described by @svetlin